# How to get CFBundleShortVersionString as a constant

Tags: ios, objective-c, version, nsbundle, compile-time-constant

I append parts to a constant base URL string in my code as such:

```
#define BASE_URL @"https://example.com/developer/"
#define PHP_SCRIPT BASE_URL @"index.php"
```

such that the resulting PHP_SCRIPT refers to `https://example.com/developer/index.php`

**I am looking for a way to insert my application's `CFBundleShortVersionString` into this concatenation.** For example, if the CFBundleShortVersionString is 1.12 I want the final URL to be `https://example.com/developer/1_12/`

I know that the `CFBundleShortVersionString` can be accessed by

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

and

```
(__bridge NSString *)(CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), kCFBundleVersionKey))
```

but I need help to concatenate it into a constant string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
#define BASE_URL @"https://example.com/developer/"
#define PHP_SCRIPT [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/", BASE_URL, [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"_"]]
```